# Compute inverse cdf of normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

How can I compute inverse CDF of normal distribution using the central limit theorem on uniform distribution (u[0,1])

Comment: no idea what type of "computation" you have in mind; the inverse CDF of the normal distribution does not have a closed form expression.

Comment: "using CLT" suggests taking a sum of many uniform randoms, and looking at the resulting CDF. Perhaps a Monte Carlo approach, or appying convolution on the uniform densities many times...

Comment: Hi Ojas Srivastava, welcome to MathOverflow! This site is for mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. Please have a look at [math.se] to ask general mathematics questions. Check [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/228959) to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely [off-topic](/help/on-topic) and better deleted here.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for bringing it to my notice. I will remember that.

Comment: @losif Pinelis yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n:=U_1+\cdots+U_n$, where $U_1,U_2,\ldots$ are iid random variables (r.v.'s) each uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then, by the central limit theorem,
\begin{equation}
    Z_n:=\frac{S_n-n/2}{\sqrt{n/12}}\to Z
\end{equation}
in distribution as $n\to\infty$, where $Z$ is a standard normal r.v. So, for each $p\in(0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
    q_n(p)\to q(p)
\end{equation}
as $n\to\infty$, where $q_n(p)$ and $q(p)$ are the $p$-quantiles of (the distributions of) $Z_n$ and $Z$, respectively, so that $q$ is the function inverse to the standard normal cdf.

Note that
\begin{equation}
    q_n(p)=\frac{X_n(p)-n/2}{\sqrt{n/12}},
\end{equation}
where $X_n(p)$ is the $p$-quantile of $S_n$, so that $X_n$ is the function inverse to the cdf of $S_n$, which let us denote by $F_n$. By the [Irwin–Hall formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), $F_n$ is piecewise polynomial; more specifically,
\begin{equation}
    k\in\{1,\dots,n\}\ \&\ k-1\le x<k\implies
    F_n(x)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\binom nj (x-j)^n. 
\end{equation}
So, the quantile/inverse functions $X_n$ and $q_n$ are piecewise algebraic.

---

Below is an image of a Mathematica notebook containing graphs of $q_2$ (red), $q_5$ (green), $q_{10}$ (blue), and $q$ (black). We see that $q_2$ already approximates $q$ well except near $0$ and $1$, with $q_5$ and $q_{10}$ significantly closer than $q_2$ to $q$ near $1$ (of course, the graphs of $q_n$ and $q$ are centrally symmetric about the point $(1/2,0)$).

[image]